# How to pass intent in this case

Tags: android

I have an activity with product details.
I am displaying product name and details in textviews.I  have stored the data in string array strings.xml file.

If within the product description, any other product name comes I have to linkify it. On click of the mentioned product link, it should show the same activity with product name and details.
I can linkify it but How can I pass intents in this case?  I have to show the same activity but different values..in textviews..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("name", productName);
intent.putExtra("details", productDetails);
```

And in the other activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String productName = bundle.getString("name");
String productDetails = bundle.getString("details");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need intent in this case. You can organize things without full restart of the activity. No need to destroy and recreate it, because the linkage is in its scope. Just change the contents of texviews.

Comment: IMO Intents are good, they'll save the state necessary to gracefully restart the activity when it is inevitably destroyed and recreated.  
Other people fighting the Intent system has caused me a lot of headaches.

Comment: I didn't say that intents are bad, I said that they are not necessary in this case - just because there is no need the whole activity to be destroyed and created again. The last can not be visually nice nor energy efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just passing the product ID, `intent.putExtra("product_id", productId)`

then in ProductDetailsActivity add

```
private Product getProduct() {
    return Products.lookup(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("product_id"));
}
```

Then in onCreate just do something like `mNameView.setText(getProduct.getName())` and similarly for mDescriptionView or whatever.